# Multiple choice question creation change checkbox to radio

Tags: 7, quiz

Using quiz module, I am creating Multiple Choice question. In that there is a check box to select the correct answer. Check box enables users to select multiple answers for a single question, but I want the users to select only one answer for a question. Is there any configuration to change that or can I change the check box to radio button. If so how can I change it to radio button? Should I change it in code base or is there any module available?

[image: check box in quiz]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, as long as you don't check the "Multiple Answers" option in the answer settings tab, your answers for that question will render with radio buttons on the front-end. This doesn't change the checkboxes to radio buttons when you are editing a question, but that's because you are supposed to be able to mark multiple correct answers for each question, if need be.